# PHP echo not posting

Tags: php, forms, echo

It's only a simple file but the PHP `echo` is not showing up.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?><br>
Your new Account is: <?php echo $_GET['accountname']; ?>

<h4>Please clarify that the information below is correct</h4>

Account Name: <?php echo $_GET['accountname']; ?>
Contact Name: <?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $_GET["lastname"]; ?>
Address: <?php echo $_GET['address']; ?> <?php echo $_GET["street"]; ?> <?php echo $_GET["direction"]; ?> <?php echo $_GET["state"]; ?> <?php echo $_GET["zip"]; ?> <?php echo $_GET["pobox"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And all it displays is  "Welcome_______" etc. It shows all the words but not the echo outputs even when there are inputs in  the form.  It's like they are all being recognized as blanks.

Comment: What URL are you using? Does it have a proper query string?

Comment: having those inputs in the form is pointless if the form hasn't been submitted yet. `$_GET` works off the url, so unless you ran this script with `http://example.com?firstname=John&accountname=foo&etc..` you won't get anything.

Comment: You should turn warnings on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings
It's probably returning `Notice: Undefined index: firstname` and so on.

Comment: i think you form work with the POST, to check it change your $_GET['firstname'] to $_POST['firstname']

Answer (score 0):

You need two files in order to better understand it.

**index.html**
*Set of data from this file will be sent for processing.*

```
<form action="account.php" method="GET">
  <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First name here...">
  <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last name here...">
  <input type="submit" value="Process data">
</form>
```

**account.php** - *Here will be data processed*

```
<?php 

  if(isset($_GET['firstname']) && isset($_GET['lastname')){
    //if all data are set, say hello
    echo "Welcome ".$firstname." ".$lastname.",";
  }else{
    //if first name or last name is not set, redirect to form
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
  }
 ?>
```

You are sending data from simple HTML form to PHP script by **GET**. Difference between GET and POST method is that, GET is posted in URL: *http://www.example.com/index.php?firstname=kamil* and POST data are sent inside of request body **(url is not changed)**. Difference is better described in this thread: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Answer (score -1):

It will work when:

http://your_url.com?firstname=xyz&accountname=abc

```
$_GET['firstname'],$_GET['accountname']
```

Or use:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @helmbert For leaving a comment you have to have 50 points ok.